# Is there any relation between these matrices?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

$Q$ is $(0,1,-1)$ vertex edge incidence matrix of a simple directed graph.
$M$ is $(0,1)$ vertex edge incidence matrix of a simple non directed graph.
$A$ is vertex vertex incidence matrix of a graph.
Is there any relation between these matrix?

I know that there is relation between Laplacian matrix and $Q$. i.e $$L=QQ^T$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388130/is-it-possible-the-m-g-1t-m-g-1-2di-l-g-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the out-degrees of the vertices as its diagonal entries, then
$$ MM^T = A + D.$$
The matrix $A+D$ is often called the unsigned Laplacian. On the other hand,
$$ M^TM = L +2I$$
where $L$ denotes the adjacency matrix of the line graph. In general there is no useful relation between the spectrum of $A$ and the spectrum of $A+D$, unless the graph is regular. If your graph is bipartite, then $D+A$ and $D-A$ are similar via a diagonal matrix with $\pm1$-entries on the diagonal.]

[Edit: for the similarity, argue as follows. Suppose the graph is bipartite on $n$ vertices, and let $S$ be the $n\times n$ diagonal matrix
with $S_{i,i}=1$ if $i$ is in the first colour class and $S_{i,i}=-1$ otherwise. Then $Q=SM$
and so $QQ^T = SMM^TS$ and therefore $D_A=S(A+D)S$. Since $S$ is orthogonal, $D+A$ and $D-A$
are similar.

Comment: @ Chris Godsil, I didn't get how bipartiteness is helping in similarity of $D+A$ and $D-A$. Can you explain a bit please.

Comment: @Sry: edited my answer.

Comment: I was a bit busy to have a look at Edit. still I am confused with this:  Let G be a graph on 3 vertices say 1,2,3. and there are two directd edges one from 1 to 2, and other from 2 to 3, Then M = [1 0; 1 1; 0 1] and Q = [1 0; 1 -1; 0 -1] (row wise matrices).   I can't figure out S. What I am missing?

Comment: @sSry: well, for a start your question and ny answer refer to undirected graphs.